# Сравнение дженериков Java

Tags: java

```
public class Student<NU,N,A,R,O> {
    private final NU nu;
    private final N n;
    private final A a;
    private final R r;
    private final O o;

    public Student(NU nu, N n, A a, R r, O o) {
        this.nu = nu;
        this.n = n;
        this.a = a;
        this.r = r;
        this.o = o;
    }

    public N getN() {
        return n;
    }
    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public R getR() {
        return r;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n Student[" +
                "Порядковый номер = " + nu +
                ", Имя = '" + n + '\'' +
                ", Возраст = " + a +
                ", Оценка = " + r +
                ", Олимпядник = " + o +
                ']' ;
    }
}

COMPARATOR 
public class StudentsComparatorsAgeAndRating implements Comparator<Student<Integer,String,Integer,Double,Boolean>> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        if (!(o1.getA().equals(o2))) {
            return (Integer)o1.getA() - (Integer)o2.getA();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
public class StudentsComparatorsName implements Comparator<Student<Integer, String, Integer, Double, Boolean>> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        return (Integer)o1.getN().toString().length() - (Integer) o2.getN().toString().length();
    }
}
public class StudentsComparatorsRating implements Comparator<Student<Integer, String, Integer, Double, Boolean>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf((Double)o1.getR());
        BigDecimal bd1 = BigDecimal.valueOf((Double)o2.getR());
        return bd1.compareTo(bd);
    }
}
```

Вопрос в том, могу ли сравнить дженерики без приведения типов?

Comment: можно сделать все их наследниками одного класса/интерфейса. и принимать Дженериков только наследников. и сравнивать только по тем полям, которые есть в родительском классе/интерфейсе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы избежать приведения типов в классах-компараторах, следует либо указывать *полный тип* в этих классах:

```java
class StudentsComparatorsAgeAndRating implements Comparator<Student<Integer,String,Integer,Double,Boolean>> {

    @Override
    public int compare(
        Student<Integer,String,Integer,Double,Boolean> o1, 
        Student<Integer,String,Integer,Double,Boolean> o2
    ) {
        if (!(o1.getA().equals(o2))) {
            return o1.getA() - o2.getA();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

так как при использовании метода `public int compare(Student o1, Student o2)` без указания конкретных классов компилятор не "понимает", какой именно класс будет применяться для полей `Student`.

Другой способ, позволяющий избавиться от излишне многословного описания компараторов: создать некий класс со спецификацией типов и конструктором, и создавать компараторы уже для такого класса:

```java
class MyStudent extends Student<Integer,String,Integer,Double,Boolean> {
    public MyStudent(Integer id, String name, Integer age, Double rating, Boolean olympic) {
        super(id, name, age, rating, olympic);
    }
}

class MyStudentComparators {
    public static Comparator<MyStudent> byAge = Comparator.comparingInt(MyStudent::getA);
    public static Comparator<MyStudent> byAgeAndRating = byAge.thenComparingDouble(MyStudent::getR);
    public static Comparator<MyStudent> byName = Comparator.comparing(MyStudent::getN);
    public static Comparator<MyStudent> byNameLength = Comparator.comparingInt(ms -> ms.getN().length());
}
```